# wakeLock.acquire(60000) after 60s still held

Tags: android, android-wake-lock

I have this piece of code:

```
WakeLock wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "MyTag");
wakeLock.acquire(60000);
//dosomething
```

I use `wakeLock.acquire(60000);` in my app,but i find on some phone(smartisan t2,vivo x7,ext),after 60s or a long time,`wakeLock.isHeld()` still `true`,the lock is not released by system.
does the phone manufacturers modify the power manager's implements?

bty,i also find on some phone,Even if I call wakelock.aqucire, the background thread still will go to sleep .